# Doesnot receive an error

Tags: php, pdo

I've an member system now I've made when somebody register an account, he need to activate it by his email. He will receive an valid link in his inbox So for example:
`activate.php?email=ipoon2@outlook.com&email_code=b5b90ae21e31229878d681680db16bdf` This link is valid so when I go to this link, he activates the account succesfully.

You see after `?email=` **ipoon2@outlook.com** So when I change that into **ipodn2@outlook.com** and the email_code is still the same, he cannot activate his account. He needs to receive an error like `We cannot find that email`, and when he changes the email_code He will receive an error like this `problem activate your account`

Thats the problem what I've got When I change the email I don't receive any error. Neither for email_code

I've a file that is called `activate.php` which this code is including:

```
<?php
} else if (isset($_GET['email'], $_GET['email_code']) === true) {
    $email  = urldecode(trim($_GET['email']));
    $email_code = trim($_GET['email_code']);
    $user = new User();
    if(User::email_exists($email) === false) {
        echo 'We cannot find that email'; // return error doesn't show up
    } else if (User::activate($email, $email_code) === false) {
        echo 'problem activate your account'; // return error doesn't show up
    }

}

?>
```

Also I've 2 functions made, there are in the class file `User.php`

```
public function email_exists($email) {  
    require './config.php';     
    $email  = urldecode(trim($_GET['email']));  
    $sql_30 =   $db->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");   
    if ($sql_30->fetch_object() === true) {         
        return true;    
    } else if ($sql_30->fetch_object() === false) {         
        return false;   
    }   
}



public function activate($email, $email_code) {
    require './config.php';
    $email  = urldecode($email);
    $email_code = $db->real_escape_string($email_code);
    $sql_33 = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `email_code` = '$email_code' AND `group` = 0");
    if ($sql_33->fetch_object()) {
        $db->query("UPDATE `users` SET `group` = 1 WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `email_code` = '$email_code'");
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You check the return of `PDO::query` by watching the type. The query return false if an error occurred. Are you sure that empty results return the type false ? In this case you will never go in the if statement.

Comment: @Debflav I don't know what I'm doing wrong, `    if(User::email_exists($email) === false) {
        echo 'We cannot find that email';
    }` He doesn't recognize this

Comment: @Benny The result of `$db->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE email = '$email'")` will give you a clue to what's going wrong.

Comment: @Jim 
`public function email_exists($email) {
 require './config.php';
    $email = urldecode(trim($_GET['email']));
 $sql_30 = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
 if ($sql_30->fetch_object()) {
  return true;
 } else {
  return false;
 }
 }`
He doesn't return the error, if the email is wrong he doesn't activate the account which need, but only the error doesn't return.

Comment: @Debflav I'm trying every thing just cannot return the error I've uploaded the code on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/RK6X7JEg which I currently have

Comment: Which code I should follow ? If now you are using `mysqli_fetch_object` : `Returns an object with string properties that corresponds to the fetched row or **NULL** if there are no more rows in resultset.`

Comment: @Debflav The third code, because `if(User::email_exists($email) === false)` AND `else if (User::activate($email, $email_code) === false)` Aren't returning false, When I put $db->results I receive an error of mysqli

Comment: @Debflav I've changed my thread hopefully you will understand what I mean now,

Answer (score 1):

To me, your email_exists() and activate() are wrong.

```
if ($sql_30->fetch_object() === true) {         
        return true;    
} else if ($sql_30->fetch_object() === false) {         
        return false;   
}
```

From the php documentation of [mysqli_result::fetch_object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php) :
`Returns an object with string properties that corresponds to the fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows in resultset.` So your test must be :

```
if ($sql_30->fetch_object() !== NULL) {         
        return true;    
} 
return false;
```

I guess it should solve your problem.

Comment: Still doesn't solve my problem,
`if(User::email_exists($email) === false) {
  echo 'We cannot find that email';
 } else if (User::activate($email, $email_code) === false) {
  echo 'problem activate your account';
 }` 
This still doesn't show up.

Comment: So your functions always return true. Is `$sql_30->num_rows > 1` in your email_exists() when provide a correct email ? I've no more idea about your problem...